# How to use "/" (directory separator) in both Linux and Windows in Python?

Tags: python, linux, windows, unix

I have written a code in python which uses / to make a particular file in a folder, if I want to use the code in windows it will not work, is there a way by which I can use the code in Windows and Linux.

In python I am using this code:

```
pathfile=os.path.dirname(templateFile)
rootTree.write(''+pathfile+'/output/log.txt')
```

When I will use my code in suppose windows machine my code will not work.

How do I use "/" (directory separator) in both Linux and Windows?

Comment: You can define it in the beginning depending on Win/*nix and then work with the variable.

Comment: In Windows you can use either \ or / as a directory separator.

Comment: Windows supports `/` in directory paths. What specific problem are you having? Post some code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Unless you depend on Windows userspace programs, forward slash works as well as backward. Some cmd commands have problems with that however.

Comment: @MichaelGeary: I have edited the question with example, Can you have a look now?

Comment: @MichaelGeary: Only sometimes. Sometimes it doesn't. (Only saying it from experience -- I don't know exactly in which situations it fails and in which it doesn't.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Do you know an example for which the Win32 API doesn't accept '/'? (not counting cmd.exe and other programs)

Comment: @eryksun: Sure; just try `PathCombine(buf, "C:/", "Temp")` and then try `PathCombine(buf, "C:\\", "Temp")`, for example. Although I'm not sure why you're discounting cmd.exe, it's kind of crucial for implementing `system()` in various languages...

Comment: @Mehrdad: `"C:/\Temp"` may be ugly, but it is a valid path. The slash or backslash can be repeated.

Comment: @eryksun: Picky, picky, are we? :) How about `PathIsRoot("C:\\") == TRUE` and `PathIsRoot("C:/") == FALSE` then? (FYI, I don't even have these memorized. I'm just trying them out right now because you asked for an example. It's easy enough to make your own, just play around with the functions.)

Comment: Have you tried `os.path.sep`?

Comment: Windows does not support unix style slash in explicit relative path of executable, i.e. e.g. `./script.py` does not work on Windows, but `.\script.py` does. Just try in cmd.exe.

Answer (score 336, accepted):

Use `os.path.join()`.
Example: `os.path.join(pathfile,"output","log.txt")`.

In your code that would be: `rootTree.write(os.path.join(pathfile,"output","log.txt"))`

Comment: `os.path.join` uses a more complex logic to match several relative path components together. When you just want to chain them, `os.sep.join` is the right choice.

Comment: So `os.sep` is the delimiter string, no thanks for the confusion.

Comment: Yes, Richard, 'os.sep' is indeed the delimiter string for the specific OS where Python is running

Answer (score 172):

Use:

```
import os
print os.sep
```

to see how separator looks on a current OS.
In your code you can use:

```
import os
path = os.path.join('folder_name', 'file_name')
```

Answer (score 98):

You can use [os.sep](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html?highlight=os.sep#os.sep):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.sep
'/'
```

Answer (score 73):

[`os.path.normpath(pathname)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) should also be mentioned as it converts `/` path separators into `\` separators on Windows. It also collapses redundant uplevel references... i.e., `A/B` and `A/foo/../B` and `A/./B` all become `A/B`.  And if you are Windows, these all become `A\B`.

Comment: This is IMO the best answer to the question as it was phrased, "how to use “/” (directory separator) in both Linux and Windows".  And it's also eminently useful -- I'd much rather do `os.path.normpath('a/b/c/d/file.ext')` than `os.path.join('a','b','c','d','file.ext')` when I need to specify a long path.

Comment: I also found this answer to be very helpful. I was looking for a method for generating paths with a consistent separator. The famous `os.path.join` just joins anything provided. e.g. `join("a/b", "c\d")` gives `a/b\c\d` (on windows). But i can get the expected result with the proper combination of `join` and `normpath`, e.g. `a\b\c\d` (on windows)

Comment: I use this import: `from os.path import normpath as normpath  # Given a Windows or Linux path, fixes path separators to match the current OS.` then I can use something like `normpath("a/b/c/d/e/f")` which seems cleaner than any alternative.

Answer (score 37):

If you are fortunate enough to be running Python 3.4+, you can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(dir, subdir, filename)  # returns a path of the system's path flavour
```

or, equivalently,

```
path = Path(dir) / subdir / filename
```

Comment: It's 2020, so **this should now be the accepted answer**. The Python devs added it to overcome problems in `os`, and it makes everything easier. Ex `path.read_text(encoding="utf8")`, `path.read_bytes()`, `path.resolve()`, `path.unlink()`, ...

Answer (score 20):

Some useful links that will help you:

- [os.sep](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep)
- [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)
- [os.pathsep](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pathsep)

Comment: pathsep? Generally useful, but not here, IMO.

Comment: @glglgl Indeed. I looked for `sep` but couldn't resist myself to post this too (I assumed the OP will found it useful for future work) :)

Comment: @Maroun `os.pathsep` is a semicolon: `;`. Recommend editing to remove.

Answer (score 13):

Do a `import os` and then use `os.sep`

Answer (score 13):

> > You can use "*os.sep* "

```
 import os
 pathfile=os.path.dirname(templateFile)
 directory = str(pathfile)+os.sep+'output'+os.sep+'log.txt'
 rootTree.write(directory)
```

Comment: It can also be written as `os.path.sep`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't build directory and file names your self, use python's included libraries.

In this case the relevant one is [os.path](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html). Especially join which creates a new pathname from a directory and a file name or directory and split that gets the filename from a full path.

Your example would be

```
pathfile=os.path.dirname(templateFile)
p = os.path.join(pathfile, 'output')
p = os.path.join( p, 'log.txt')
rootTree.write(p)
```

Answer (score 5):

If someone is looking for something like this:

He/she wants to know the parent directory and then go to the sub-folders and maybe than to a specific file. If so, I use the following approach.

1. I am using python 3.9 as of now. So in that version, we have the **os** module for handling such tasks. So, for getting the parent directory:

> ```
> parent_dir = os.path.pardir
> ```

2. It's a good coding practice to not hardcode the file path separators (/ or \). Instead, use the operating system dependant mechanism provided by the above-mentioned **os** module. It makes your code very much reusable for other purposes/people. It goes like this (just an example) :

> `path = os.path.pardir + os.sep + 'utils' + os.sep + 'properties.ini'`
>
> `print(f'The path to my global properties file is :: {path}')`

Output:

> ..\utils\properties.ini

*You can surely look at the whole documentation here :* https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Answer (score 0):

I use `pathlib` for most things, so I like: **`pathlib.os.sep`**.

Usually `pathlib` is the better choice if you don't need `os`!