# Python: can't create subdirectory

Tags: python

I want to apply a test to list of files.  The files that past the test should be moved to the directory "Pass"; the others should be moved to the directory "Fail".

Thus the output directory should contain subdirectories "Pass" and "Fail".

Here is my attempt:

```
        if(<scan==pass>) # Working fine up to this point
            dest_dir = outDir + '\\' + 'Pass'  # The problem is here
            print("Pass", xmlfile)
            MoveFileToDirectory(inDir, xmlfile, dest_dir)
        else:
            dest_dir = os.path.dirname(outDir + '\\' + 'Fail')
            print("Fail: ", xmlfile)
            MoveFileToDirectory(inDir, xmlfile, dest_dir)
```

However, my code is moving the files to the output directory and not creating the "Pass" or "Fail" subdirectories.  Any ideas why?

Comment: `if(<scan==pass>)` is not valid syntax at all, what is supposed to be testing?

Comment: are you sure about your syntax? forgetting about intentation, what does `<...>` do? and `pass` is a keyword. you should never use it as a variable. i think you can't even...

Comment: this is something i used according to my program,for the example i typed like this.

Comment: Yes I am sure pass is a keyword in lower case, to resolve ambiguity you can use Passed. my code is fine with identation while posting it appeared like this@hiro

Comment: `if(<scan==pass>)` makes absolutely no sense and is not fine, the problem is that line

Comment: It also misses a colon after the if, and it's unusual to wrap conditions in parentheses. A simple `if thecondition:` suffices.

Comment: HK0909: I get what you did with <scan==pass>, and simplification is good, but use something that is at least syntactically correct; e.g. `if( conditionTrue ):`

Comment: @JohnPirie, what is `if(<scan==pass>)` doing exactly?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I think OP just had some big wacky condition there that he is trying to spare us from looking at.  It's just a true/false condition of some kind, not germane to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use os.path.join(). Example:

```
os.path.join(outDir, 'Pass')
```

[See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010992/how-to-use-directory-separator-in-both-linux-and-windows)

Also, we don't know what `MoveFileToDirectory` does.  Use the standard `os.rename`:

```
os.rename("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/desination/for/file.foo")
```

[See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/moving-a-file-in-python)

So:

```
source_file = os.path.join(inDir, xmlfile)
if(conditionTrue):
    dest_file = os.path.join(outDir, 'Pass', xmlfile)
    print("Pass: ", xmlfile)
else:
    dest_file = os.path.join(outDir, 'File', xmlfile)
    print("Fail: ", xmlfile)
os.rename(source_file, dest_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create directories exactly once:

```
import os

labels = 'Fail', 'Pass'
dirs = [os.path.join(out_dir, label) for label in labels]
for d in dirs:
    try:
        os.makedirs(d)
    except EnvironmentError:
        pass # ignore errors
```

Then you could move files into the created directories:

```
import shutil

print("%s: %s" % (labels[condition_true], xmlfile))
shutil.move(os.path.join(out_dir, xmlfile), dirs[condition_true])
```

The code exploits that `False == 0` and `True == 1` in Python.