# how can I add r' into variable in python?

Tags: python, path

I have two functions in my program one will take the path from user and another will open the file in that path, this function will open the file

```
def pdfparser(filename):
    fp = file(filename, 'rb')
```

when I pass the path from another function it returns:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\advisor\\website\\a.PDF
```

I know I have to add double splash to the path or (r'path)
but my question how can I add r' or double slash into variable since the path will be stored in variable and pass into another function. I need something like s=r'path

any help please

Comment: The r prefix is only for constants. Once the string has the correct value, no need to specify r prefix again. Are you sure the file exists on your system? Try to print `filename` just before opening it, and copy/paste it in a windows explorer to see it windows finds it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question (is the IOError really complete? What about the stacktrace), but what does not work with `filename = r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\advisor\website\a.PDF` besides os.path.join() being far cooler ...?

Comment: Your error indicates the filename was correctly specified; all the backslashes are correct. The problem you have is *not* one that can be solved with prefixing `r` somewhere. Note that `r'...'` is just a *syntax* to specify a string value, it is not a separate object type. It just tells the *parser* not to interpret `\..` escape sequences. Because this is a *syntax concept* there is no *dynamic counterpart*.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre it exists I have tried that but when I pass 'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\advisor\website\a.PDF it does not work but when I add double slash or r' works but the idea my path is sorted within a variable so how can I add r' or double space

Comment: @Dilettant  I can't add r' into path because my path within variable in another function

Comment: I would recommend using os.path.join but if you receive it already concat then maybe [python : how to convert string literal to raw string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262828/python-how-to-convert-string-literal-to-raw-string-literal) is where you find your way "out" of the dilemma ;-)

Comment: If I know how change single slash into double slash it would be very easy for me

Comment: Show the whole error message. At least until the end of the line.

Comment: @StefanPochmann    fp = file(filename, 'rb')                                     IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\advisor\\website\\a.PDF

Comment: @angela If that's the whole line, then that's likely your problem. The string starts with `'C:\\Users` but never ends (there's no ending `'`). So I guess there's a line break at the end and it continues on the next line somehow?

Comment: @StefanPochmann  that function it works when I pass path manually include double slash , But when I pass the path  from user it gives me that error so l know my mistake which is from single slash I have to double slash but I don't know HOW !!! since my   path within variable

Comment: @angela Do `print repr(filename)` right before `fp = file(filename, 'rb')` and show what that prints.

Comment: it seems it doubled the slash
'C:\\Users\\userl\\PycharmProjects\x07dvisor\\website\\media\transcripts\x07yse.PDF' and same error but when I store it in variable . for example s=repr(filename) then fb=file(s,'rb') it returns 'C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\PycharmProjects\\x07dvisor\\\\website\\\\media\\transcripts\\x07yse.PDF'" and same error but change it the slash

Comment: That string is pretty broken, no wonder it doesn't work. No idea how you got the bell character `\x07` and the tab character `\t` in there. Don't try `file(repr(filename), ...)`, that makes no sense.

Comment: To be clear: The point of using `repr` was to see the value of the string. Not to create double backslashes for you to use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010992/how-to-use-directory-separator-in-both-linux-and-windows may help.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

Before calling this function, store the path value in any variable say, 'directory', here u add the prefix r' in filepath. When calling this  pdfparser(filename) function, just pass 'directory' as argument. It works!

```
>directory= r"C:\Users\SomeUser\Pictures\Disk"  
>pdfparser(directory)
```

Comment: At first sight, I was afraid this could not work. But after tested it, it just worked.