# How to get an absolute file path in Python? (Get rid of backslashes)

Tags: python, path, relative-path, absolute-path

Given a path such as "mydir/myfile.txt", how do I find the file's absolute path relative to the current working directory in Python? E.g. on Windows, I might end up with:

`"C:/example/cwd/mydir/myfile.txt"`.

I tried: `mypath = os.path.abspath("../mydir/myfile.txt")`. But I got:

```py
>> print(mypath)
C:\example\cwd\mydir\myfile.txt
```

Note that when I execute `mypath` I have `C:\\example\\cwd\\mydir\\myfile.txt`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the expected output when given `"mydir/myfile.txt"` ? The absolute path to the file `"C:/example/cwd/mydir/myfile.txt"` ? The relative path from the current dir to the file `"../mydir/myfile.txt"` ? Or is it a problem of "path separtor" (e.g. slashes `/` vs backslashes `\\`) ?

Comment: I want to get to `myfile.txt`. I want to type `"../mydir/myfile.txt"` instead of `"C:/example/cwd/mydir/myfile.txt"` so when I'll share my code, they can reuse my code without changing their directory because `"/mydir/myfile.txt"` is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer to my comment, what you want is to use a **relative** path to the file, not the **absolute** path to the file.
I recommend you to use [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) to compute the relative path from your current working directory to the file :

```py
import os.path

# inputs
absolute_path_to_file = r"C:\example\cwd\mydir\myfile.txt"
current_working_directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)  # C:\example\cwd\my_other_dir

# using os.path.relpath
relative_path_from_current_working_directory_to_file = \
    os.path.relpath(absolute_path_to_file, current_working_directory)

# result
print(relative_path_from_current_working_directory_to_file)  # ..\mydir\myfile.txt
```

If you want, you can omit the second parameter to `os.path.relpath` (named `start`) because it defaults to your current directory (see [`os.curdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.curdir)), so that you can simply do :

```py
relative_path_from_current_working_directory_to_file = \
    os.path.relpath(absolute_path_to_file)
```

Comment: Also, you mix forward slahes (`/`) and backward slashes (`\ `). The backward ones are used mainly on Windows, the others everywhere else. In general, it is better to not mix them up, it may cause your program to not work properly, or people to not understand your questions.

Answer (score 0):

What would you expect instead of the `C:\example\cwd\mydir\myfile.txt` ?

What you see is an absolute Windows Filepath.
Windows uses backslashes for its filepaths, while Linux resorts to forward slashes.
The python `os.path` package automatically handles the conversion, thus although you enter a Linux-style path (at least almost, because Linux does not know about drives like C:), it automatically converts to Windows (as you run the code on a Windows machine).

Also see: [What is the filepath difference between window and linux in python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845415/what-is-the-filepath-difference-between-window-and-linux-in-python3)