# I got File not found error and it seems not an encoding problem

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, file-not-found, tabula

I am using tabula to read pdf tables, but get the file not found error, i have tried chardet (https://pypi.org/project/chardet/#files) to find if there is any encoding problem, but encoding was None.

```
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate
df = read_pdf('C:\\Users\\YQ\IPA.pdf')
df
```

---

> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call
>   last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabula\wrapper.py in
>   read_pdf(input_path, output_format, encoding, java_options,
>   pandas_options, multiple_tables, **kwargs)
>       107     try:
>   --> 108         output = subprocess.check_output(args)
>       109
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs,
>   **kwargs)
>       388     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
>   --> 389                **kwargs).stdout
>       390
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout,
>   check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
>       465 
>   --> 466     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>       467         try:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in **init**(self, args, bufsize,
>   executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd,
>   env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals,
>   start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
>       768                                 errread, errwrite,
>   --> 769                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
>       770         except:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args,
>   executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo,
>   creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread,
>   errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)    1171
>   os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
>   -> 1172                                          startupinfo)    1173             finally:
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> JavaNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 df = read_pdf('C:\Users\YQ\IPA.pdf')
>         2 df
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tabula\wrapper.py in
>   read_pdf(input_path, output_format, encoding, java_options,
>   pandas_options, multiple_tables, **kwargs)
>       109 
>       110     except FileNotFoundError as e:
>   --> 111         raise JavaNotFoundError(JAVA_NOT_FOUND_ERROR)
>       112 
>       113     except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
>
> JavaNotFoundError: `java` command is not found from this Python
>   process. Please ensure Java is installed and PATH is set for `java`

Comment: I think the problem is with the path you are giving. `C:\\Users\\YQ\IPA.pdf` . The `\\` varies with operating system. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010992/how-to-use-directory-separator-in-both-linux-and-windows-in-python for more information

Comment: The last one looks like java is required and could not be found.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however, i am using windows and this path was copied from the system and i have tried'/' as well. this still doesnt work.