# Matplotlib figure is not saving in a specific folder

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to save matplotlib figure in `r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\binary_image"`. but instead of saving figure in `binary_image` folder figure is saving in `Handcrafted dataset`  folder. And the image name is becoming `binary_image0.png`. But i want to save figure in my desired directory as `i.png` .How can i fix this?

```
di=r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\binary_image"
for i,img in enumerate(images):
    img = rgb2gray(img)
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.imshow(img ,cmap='gray')
    plt.savefig(di+str(i)+".png")
```

Comment: I think you may need  to add the folder separator `\ ` between folder name and image name.
Try `plt.savefig(di+"\\"+str(i)+".png")`?
A nicer OS-independent solution would be to use os.path.join as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010992/how-to-use-directory-separator-in-both-linux-and-windows-in-python) and do `img_name = str(i)+".png"` and `os.path.join(di, img_name)`

Comment: thanks! i have used first method and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a backslash:

```
plt.savefig(save_to + '\' + str(i) + '.png')
```

Note: `dir` is a build-in function -- do not name your variable like that.

---

Answer (score 1):

Using `os.path.join` or `pathlib.Path` is better.

```
import os

fn = "file_{}.png".format(i)
fn = os.path.join(dir, fn)
plt.savefig(fn)
```

or

```
from pathlib import Path

dir = Path(dir)
fn = dir / "file_{}.png".format(i)
plt.savefig(fn)
```