# print pdf file to printer, Python 3.10.6

Tags: python

I have a function that convert the generated .docx file to .PDF and save it to the directory, after the save I want to print it to the printer.

I am having problem with the fileName, I am not able to read the directory.

```
pywintypes.error: (2, 'ShellExecute', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

I am using `win32api.ShellExecute()` for printing.

```
doc.save("./cr/generated_doc"+itemid1+".docx")
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
convert("./cr/generated_doc"+itemid1+".docx",
        "./cr/pdf/label"+itemid1+".pdf")

printername = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
fileName = str(r"./cr/pdf/label"+itemid1+".pdf")
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "printto", filename, f'"{printername}"', ".", 0)

os.remove("./cr/generated_doc"+itemid1+".docx")
os.remove(fullnm)
```

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path?

Comment: Why would having a different file name each time prevent you from using an absolute path?

Comment: @user3738870  you mean trying like this?  
            printername = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
            filename = './cr/pdf/label"+itemid1+".pdf'
            abs_path = os.path.abspath(filename)
            win32api.ShellExecute(0, "printto", abs_path,
                                  f'"{printername}"', ".", 0)

Comment: @user3738870  with the path like this it works,  filename = 'C:\Users\jimi\Desktop\folder\test.pdf'

Comment: Oh I see, then it's a Windows problem. You have to use \ instead of /, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010992/how-to-use-directory-separator-in-both-linux-and-windows-in-python for more details

Comment: @user3738870 still not working:              filename = str(r'.\cr\pdf\label"+itemid1+".pdf')
            win32api.ShellExecute(0, "printto", filename,
                                  f'"{printername}"', ".", 0)

Comment: @user3738870   pywintypes.error: (2, 'ShellExecute', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

Comment: What is `fullnm`?

Comment: What's the difference between `filename` and `fileName`?

Comment: For paths, use Python's pathlib, it will solve many problems portably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, directories are separated by `\` in paths instead of `/`. In order to handle paths OS-independently, you have to use a Python helper function, `os.path.join`. Using this, your code should not encounter path-related errors:

```py
doc_file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("cr", "generated_doc"+itemid1+".docx"))
pdf_file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("cr", "pdf", "label"+itemid1+".pdf"))
doc.save(doc_file_path)
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
convert(doc_file_path, pdf_file_path)

printername = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "printto", pdf_file_path, f'"{printername}"', ".", 0)

os.remove(doc_file_path)
os.remove(fullnm)
```

Comment: I get an error:   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Jimi\\Desktop\\labelsnep\\cr\\generated_docAC0030.docx'

Comment: That seems like a separate issue. I recommend opening a new question.