# How can I fix the AssertionError in my Django test case for image path generation in models?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created test case for generating the  image path and added the function in the models for generating the image path

I got the following error
AssertionError: 'uploads\recipe\test-uuid.jpg' != 'uploads/recipe/test-uuid.jpg'

- uploads\recipe\test-uuid.jpg
  ?        ^      ^

- uploads/recipe/test-uuid.jpg
  ?        ^      ^

```
@patch('core.models.uuid.uuid4')

    def test_recipe_file_name_uuid(self,mock_uuid):
        '''test generating image path'''

        uuid="test-uuid"
        mock_uuid.return_value=uuid
        file_path=models.recipe_image_file_path(None,"example.jpg")
        self.assertEqual(file_path,f'uploads/recipe/{uuid}.jpg')
```

and the recipe_image_file_path in the models file is as follows

```
def recipe_image_file_path(instance,filename):
    '''generating a file path for the new recipe image'''

    ext=os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    filename=f'{uuid.uuid4()}{ext}'

    return os.path.join('uploads','recipe',filename)
```

When I run test case I want to match the assertEqual(file_path,f'uploads/recipe/{uuid}.jpg')

Comment: use from pathlib import Path, instead of os.path, https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f

Comment: Pathlib is the correct answer - @Jisson should add this as a (slightly more detailed than the comment) answer so it can be accepted. Don't try and work out the system and the seperators as the other answer says ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running code in Windows. Windows and Linux has [different path separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010992/how-to-use-directory-separator-in-both-linux-and-windows-in-python)

- Windows: `\`
- Linux: `/`

To be able run your code on both OSes you have to change `f'uploads/recipe/{uuid}.jpg'` part to

```py
path_to_compare = os.path.join('uploads', 'recipe', f'{uuid}.jpg')
```

or

```py
path_to_compare = f'uploads{os.sep}recipe{os.sep}{uuid}.jpg'
```

or

```py
from pathlib import Path
path_to_compare = str(Path.joinpath(Path('uploads'), 'recipe', f'{uuid}.jpg'))
```

And final assertion check should be looks like:

```py
self.assertEqual(file_path, path_to_compare)
```

---

Or, if you want to use `Path` instead of strings you have to update **return value and asssertion check** like:

```py
def recipe_image_file_path(instance,filename):
    ...
    return Path('uploads') / 'recipe' / filename
```

and

```py
self.assertEqual(file_path, Path('uploads') / 'recipe' / f'{uuid}.jpg')
```

Comment: Yeah, don't do this. Use Pathlib.

Comment: @michjnich This answer is about `How to fix AssertionError` but not what is better `os` or `pathlib`

Comment: @michjnich I added `pathlib` solution. But personally I can't see reason why `os` can't be used here or why `pathlib` is better **in this case**

Comment: The assertion error exists because your path is not matching. If you set a path using pathlib it can be OS independant and you know it will be correct whatever OS you are on. Added benefit - easier to read than using `os.path.join`

Comment: @michjnich `If you set a path using pathlib it can be OS independent` → all three variants in this answer are OS independent.

Comment: If you really prefer `f'uploads{os.sep}recipe{os.sep}{uuid}.jpg'` to `"uploads" / "recipe" / f"{uuid}.jpg"` then go for it. I'm not trying to evangelise here, just stating what is the general recommendation these days, and what will make life easier for you.

Comment: When I try pathlib I got the same path but it adds prefix of windows path and results in the error can you solve this for me
AssertionError: WindowsPath('uploads/recipe/test-uuid.jpg') != 'uploads/recipe/test-uuid.jpg'

Comment: @Narendrayadav I added details in my answer. If you updated your code according my answer `AssertionError: WindowsPath('uploads/recipe/test-uuid.jpg') != 'uploads/recipe/test-uuid.jpg'` will never be happen.